# route provider how to pass a dependency into a controller

Tags: angularjs

if I have the following angularjs code route provider how can I pass through a dependency into the blaCtrl controller please?

Many thanks,

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/bla', { templateUrl: 'bla.html', controller: 'blaCtrl' });
```

**trying to get something like**

```
'use strict';
app.controller('blaCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.mydata = ['111', '222', '333'];  // how can I change this to be a method call to a dependency, i.e.
    $scope.mydata = mydependency.getData();  // example what I need
```

});

**update**

My app file looks like this - I'm still not getting the data displayed?

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {    
  $routeProvider.when('/application', { templateUrl: 'partials/application.html', controller: 'myCtrl' });
  $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/application' });
}]);
```

**controller**

```
'use strict';

app.controller('myCtrl', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    debugger;  // doesn't get hit?
    $scope.stuff = myService.getStuff();
});
```

**console error**

```
  - I get this error in the console Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/ng/areq?p0=applicationCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways of dependency annotation according to [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation).

#### Inline Array Annotation

In this case your controller defenition should look like:

```
'use strict';
app.controller('blaCtrl', ['$scope', 'mydependency', function ($scope, mydependency) {
    $scope.mydata = mydependency.getData();
}]);
```

#### $inject Property Annotation

```
'use strict';
var blaCtrl = function ($scope, mydependency) {
    $scope.mydata = mydependency.getData();
};
blaCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'mydependency'];
app.controller('blaCtrl', blaCtrl);
```

#### Implicit Annotation

This one you used in your example code to inject `$scope` variable. Not recommended, minificattion will broke such code.

```
'use strict';
app.controller('blaCtrl', function ($scope, mydependency) {
    $scope.mydata = mydependency.getData();
});
```

The fact that you reference your controller not in HTML but in `routeProvider` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: thanks - i've updated my question with my attempt although I'm still failing

Comment: You should either delete `'myService'` from before `function ($scope, myService)` or wrap all construction after `'myCtrl'` in array. Your controller declaration is not valid now

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a dependency to the controller from within the controller. You're injecting the $scope dependency already, and you can inject others like $location and $rootScope if you'd like.

Comment: is there any example?  I'm just starting with AngularJS

Comment: Sure!

Heres a screenshot of one of my projects:

[here](http://i.imgur.com/yt0chT3.png)

Be sure your dependencies remain in the same order